# Cannot execute sql INSERT query (mysql_query) in php script. PHP/MySQL -- Time Sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

UPDATE: NOW RESOLVED - Thanks everyone!

Fix:  I had a column named "referred_by" and in my code it's called "referred_by_id" - so it was trying to INSERT to a column that didn't exist -- once I fixed this, it decided to work!

I have limited time left to work on this project.  The clock is ticking.

I'm trying to INSERT $php_variables into a TABLE called "clients".

I've been trying for hours to get this script to work, and I got it to work once, but then I realized I forgot a field, so I had to add another column to the TABLE and when I updated the script it stopped working.  I reverted by but now it's still not working and I'm just frustrating myself too much.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if (!isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
    header ("Location: ./login.php");
}

else
{
    include ("./source.php");
    echo $doctype;
}

$birthday = $birth_year . "-" . $birth_month . "-" . $birth_day;
$join_date = date("Y-m-d");

$error_type = 0;

$link = mysql_connect("SERVER", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

if (!$link)
{
    $error = "Cannot connect to MySQL.";
    $error_type = 1;
}

$select_db = mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $link);

if (!$select_db)
{
    $error = "Cannot connect to Database.";
    $error_type = 2;
}

if ($referred_by != "")
{
    $result = mysql_query("
    SELECT id FROM clients WHERE referral_code = $referred_by
    ");

    if (!$result)
    {
        $error = "Cannot find referral.";
        $error_type = 3;
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $referred_by_id = $row['id'];
    }
}

else
{
    $referred_by_id = 0;
}

$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
$birth_month = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birth_month']);
$birth_day = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birth_day']);
$birth_year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['birth_year']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
$zip_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip_code']);
$phone_home = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_home']);
$phone_cell = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_cell']);
$referral_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['referral_code']);
$referred_by = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['referred_by']);
$organization = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['organization']);
$gov_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gov_type']);
$gov_code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gov_code']);

$test_query = mysql_query
("
INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, birthday, join_date, email, address, city, state, zip_code,
phone_home, phone_cell, referral_code, referred_by_id, organization, gov_type, gov_code)
VALUES ('".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$birthday."', '".$join_date."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zip_code."',
'".$phone_home."', '".$phone_cell."', '".$referral_code."', '".$referred_by_id."', '".$organization."', '".$gov_type."', '".$gov_code."')
");

if (!$test_query)
{
    die(mysql_error($link));
}

if ($error_type > 0)
{
    $title_name = "Error";
}

if ($error_type == 0)
{
    $title_name = "Success";
}

?>


<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title . " - " . $title_name; ?></title>
        <?php echo $meta; ?>
        <?php echo $style; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $logo; ?>
        <?php echo $sublogo; ?>
        <?php echo $nav; ?>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="main">

                <span class="event_title"><?php echo $title_name; ?></span><br><br>

                <?php

                if ($error_type == 0)
                {
                    echo "Client was added to the database successfully.";
                }

                else
                {
                    echo $error;
                }

                ?>

            </div>
            <?php echo $copyright ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please output an error message with mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: just an advice: use parametrized queries, otherwise you will get into much more trouble (SQL Injection, invalid SQL, etc).

Comment: This isn't a public page so I don't really have to worry about injection :/

Comment: If you can't access mysql_error (never seen that before) then why don't you echo your query and try to run on DB directly.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and   
`ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to your script and post the results.

Comment: @sberry2A the page is always blank as far as mysql_error() goes.  I did try inserting directly and it worked earlier - it's just in the php script where I'm having problems :/

Comment: @Tuga alright, it's now displaying errors - thanks for that little tip. I'll update the question with the errors in 2 minutes.

Comment: Or move your connection statements above the mysql_real_escape_string() calls. Also - I'm concerned about the constant 'query' error - don't see that in the code.

Comment: @Doug OK - that got rid of all the errors! However, I checked the DB and nothing has been added.

Comment: @Doug I mislabeled a column! It is now working - thanks Doug!

Comment: @tactzer0 - This is exactly the sort of problem I was attempting to alleviate with my code suggestion (not to mention that I pointed out the if/else error first as well).

Comment: @John #1 Tuga beat you. #2 Your code suggestions other than the error had nothing to do with the problem. I mislabeled the column in my table. #3 Your code might be more efficient - but it's definitely not easier for me to read.  There's really nothing wrong with the way I have it either.  As long as there's some consistency with spacing/line-breaking/indentation -- it's fine.

Comment: I don't really care that much, but: 1).  No, I beat him by nearly 10 minutes.  For #s 2 & 3... I expect you'll learn with time that the reason a senior guy makes these kinds of suggestions is from experience, but that's fine, since I know that if you keep coding you'll agree one day.  However, in the meantime you really must make sure to escape incoming strings and you really have to dump the old `mysql` interface in favor of `mysqli` -- it is slower, less secure, and marked for exclusion from upcoming PHP releases.  Have fun & happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've an error on line 81:

```
else
{
    $referred_by_id = 0;
}
```

I don't see an IF construct before that, make the appropriate correction and run the script again.

Comment: It was this in combination with a mislabeled column - thanks Tuga!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not working as is.  Looks you have a 500 error, since you have an else with a missing if:

```
else
{
    $referred_by_id = 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to post your DB schema.

Also, note that you're really taking the long way around with this code, which makes it difficult to read & maintain.  You're also missing any sort of checks for SQL injection... you really need to pass things through mysql_real_escape_string (and really, you should use mysqli, since the mysql interface was basically deprecated years ago).

```
$keys = array('first_name',
    'last_name',
    'birthday', 
    'join_date', 
    'email', 
    'address', 
    'city', 
    'state', 
    'zip_code',
    'phone_home', 
    'phone_cell', 
    'referral_code', 
    'referred_by_id', 
    'organization', 
    'gov_type', 
    'gov_code');

$_REQUEST['birthdate'] = $_REQUEST['birth_year'].'-'.$_REQUEST['birth_month'].'-'.$_REQUEST['birth_day'];
$_REQUEST['join_date'] = date('Y-m-d',time());

$params = array();
foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    $params[] = mysql_real_escape_string($request[$key]);
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO clients ('.implode(',', $keys).') ';
$sql .= ' VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $params).'\') ';
```

Comment: $params should be set as `$params[] = '"'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$key]) .'"'`, I believe.

Comment: @Doug Kress - Thank you, that's what I get for writing code off the top of my head.  : )

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the table structure to make sure all the fields are there, I'm going to assume it's something with the data.

Any quotes in the data will lead to problems (including SQL injection security holes). You should wrap each $_POST[] with mysql_real_escape_string(), such as:

```
$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
```

EDIT: Further debugging...

As someone suggested (sorry, can't find the comment), try:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, birthday, join_date, email, address, city, state, zip_code,
    phone_home, phone_cell, referral_code, referred_by_id, organization, gov_type, gov_code)
    VALUES ('".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$birthday."', '".$join_date."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$city."', '".$state."', '".$zip_code."',
        '".$phone_home."', '".$phone_cell."', '".$referral_code."', '".$referred_by_id."', '".$organization."', '".$gov_type."', '".$gov_code."'
    )";

// Debug:
print "<pre>". $sql ."</pre>";

mysql_query($sql);
```

The SQL statement should be printed out when submitting the form. Take that SQL statement and try to execute it directly in MySQL to see if it works, or if it generates an error.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about injection since it's not a public page.  But I'll try this anyway if it helps with errors.  I'll report back in a minute or two.